# How to pass the content of a text box to set camera in google earth plugin?

Tags: javascript, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Currently I am working with a Google Earth Plugin code. At this moment I am trying to move the camera according the content of certain text boxes. This is the code i currently have.

```
var ge;

google.load("earth", "1");

function init() {
  google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCallback, failureCallback);
//create boxes
  addSampleUIHtml(
    '<input id="Altitude" type="text" value="500000"/>');
  addSampleUIHtml(
    '<input id="Longitude" type="text" value="2"/>');
  addSampleUIHtml(
    '<input id="Latitude" type="text" value="42"/>');  
  addSampleUIHtml(
    '<input id="Heading" type="text" value="0"/>');  
  addSampleUIHtml(
    '<input id="Tilt" type="text" value="0"/>');
  addSampleUIHtml(
    '<input id="Roll" type="text" value="0"/>');    
  addSampleButton('Move the camera', buttonClick);
}

function initCallback(instance) {
  ge = instance;
  ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

  // just for debugging purposes
  document.getElementById('installed-plugin-version').innerHTML =
    ge.getPluginVersion().toString();
}

function failureCallback(errorCode) {
}

function buttonClick() {

  var AltitudeInBox=document.getElementById('Altitude').value

  var CameraAt= ge.getView().copyAsCamera(ge.ALTITUDE_ABSOLUTE);
  CameraAt.set   (  41.383, // latitude +-90
                               2.183 , // longitude +-180
                               AltitudeInBox, // altitude (m)
                               ge.ALTITUDE_ABSOLUTE, // reference altitude mode
                               0,  //heading Direction (that is, North, South, East, West), in degrees. Default=0 (North). Values range from 0 to 360 degrees
                               0, //Tilt 0 to 360 degrees.
                               0 //Rotation, in degrees around the Z axis. -180 to +180 degrees.

  ge.getView().setAbstractView(CameraAt)
}
```

When I define the variable AltitudeInBox as the content of the box Altitude the valor is passed to this. I cheeked using the alert function (alert(AltitudeInBox);), however when i pass the variable AltitudeInBox as argument of the function CameraAt.set I don't get any result.
I suspect that the variable AltitudeInBox is assigned as a chart instead a number but no idea how to change it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the solution. It was a beginners mistake.  The following statement:

```
 var AltitudeInBox=document.getElementById('Altitude').value
```

Assign the content of the Altitude box as a chart variable, but the following code expects a number

```
   CameraAt.set   (  41.383, // latitude +-90
                               2.183 , // longitude +-180
                               AltitudeInBox, // altitude (m)
                               ge.ALTITUDE_ABSOLUTE, // reference altitude mode
                               0,  //heading Direction (that is, North, South, East,West), in degrees. Default=0 (North). Values range from 0 to 360 degrees
                               0, //Tilt 0 to 360 degrees.
                               0 //Rotation, in degrees around the Z axis. -180 to +180degrees.
```

The solution would be to use parseFloat() or parseInt(), like this.

```
   CameraAt.set   (  parseFloat(document.getElementById('Latitude').value),
                     parseFloat(document.getElementById('Longitude').value) ,
                     parseFloat(document.getElementById('Altitude').value), 
                     ge.ALTITUDE_ABSOLUTE, //altitude mode
                     parseFloat(document.getElementById('Heading').value),
                     parseFloat(document.getElementById('Tilt').value),
                     parseFloat(document.getElementById('Roll').value)    )
```